# histogram equalization skimage

Tags: python, image-processing, rgb, scikit-image

I'm tryng to get some statics from some images, and when I tryed to perform histogram equalization I get confused.

Because I tryed this:

```
img = io.imread(file);
img = exposure.equalize_hist(img);
```

And I get the warning `warn("This might be a color image. The histogram will be "`

Then I tryed to perform the equalization in each channel like this:

```
img = io.imread(file);
#img = exposure.equalize_hist(img);    
height, width = len(img), len(img[0]);
r1 = [];
g1 = [];
b1 = [];
for i in range(height):
    for j in range(width): 
        pixel = img[i, j];
        r1.append(pixel[0]);
        g1.append(pixel[1]);
        b1.append(pixel[2]);    
r = exposure.equalize_hist(r1);        
g = exposure.equalize_hist(g1);
b = exposure.equalize_hist(b1);
```

And I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

So how should I do histogram equalization in an image with color, and if I wanna do it in an image in HSV, or CIELAB, is it the same way?!
[histogram equalization](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_equalize.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-color-exposure-plot-equalize-py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To equalize each channel separately:

```
from skimage import io, exposure


img = io.imread(img_path)

for channel in range(img.shape[2]):  # equalizing each channel
    img[:, :, channel] = exposure.equalize_hist(img[:, :, channel])
```

That's because `img[:, :, channel]` already gives you the 2d image array supported by `equalize_hist`, so that you don't need to create three lists (which may be considerably inefficient, by the way). The code supposes that you do have a image (3d array) with channels on the last dimension (which is the case if you load it with `skimage.io.imread`).

Also, it should work the same with RGB, HSV of Lab (skimage conversions will keep channels on the last dimension). For example `img = color.rgb2hsv(img)` or `img = color.rgb2lab(img)`.

If you load a grey-scale image (already a 2d array), then your commented line should work (you could handle both cases with a simple if condition).

Just something else: you can drop the semicolons.

Comment: I think I got but now I got strange values on img, before on img[0] I had [[179 138 172]
 [179 136 164]
 ..., 
 [168 105 134]
 [173 112 143]] and now I got  all zeros: [[0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 ..., 
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]
 [0 0 0]]. Is it right?

Comment: Maybe, it'd be best to convert to HSV and operate on the V channel.  Also, rescaling intensities is often better for preserving data than histogram equalization.